# Laravel localization, redirect to the right view

Tags: php, laravel, localization, multilingual

I'm using laravel and mcamara/laravel-localization package to manage a bilingual site (french/english).
In the package documention https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization 
they don't explain how to point an URL to the right view depending on which language is set as local.

For example, if the URL is **/en/contact** load the view **en.contact** (en is the subdirectory for views written in english) and id the URL is **/fr/contact** load the view from the subdirectory **fr**. 
The same for the URL that needs translation **/en/products** for english needs to load **/fr/produits** when the local language is set to french.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I have never used the package...*

That's because the package (and also the localization of laravel) assume that you are using [Laravel's translations](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/localization). So the package basically only worries about setting the application locale right and Laravel does the rest of the job.

However if you need different views (or don't want to use translations) you can just retrieve the current locale and use it to build the name of the view

```
View::make(App::getLocale().'.contact');
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the view-path dynamically, so you dont have to prefix your views by hand.

Just create a new Middleware and register it in Kernel.php.
I've created a gist for that.
https://gist.github.com/vanderb/80dea9a8039dd60962c5cb291eae7b75

Now, all you have to do is to reference the view-name, without adding the lang-code every time.

I also recommend to use named-routes
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#named-routes

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you would want to use different views for each language. That would double your code. Just use one view with Laravels own translation features to translate your strings. The package handles the naming of routes (/products vs /produits). The views should stay the same.

If you really want different views for different languages, @lukasgeiter has the answer. Sounds like a code-duplication, though.

Side-note: Laravel 5.4s new JSON translation feature together with [langman](https://github.com/themsaid/laravel-langman-gui) is really great.

Comment: I disagree! There is at least one big use-case where this is extremely useful: when you have a view with *a lot* of text, such as a Terms & Conditions page or an FAQ.

In normal cases, of course, you are right.